# Displaying entire JAVA Web application in Chinese language

Tags: java

I am having a java application. My goal is to display the web pages in Chinese language.CONSTRAINT: Client is not happy with GOOGLE TRANSLATE.

-Is there any other way to display it in Chinese language with out using these kind of translators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had to display ours in Japanese. Only way to do it right is to use resource bundles and have someone actually translate it. You need someone who understands the context being used in each language.

For example, "Close Window" when translated using translators like Google translated to something like "close window" (the type you have in your room). So there is not always a direct literal translation.

Comment: Agreed. This is what I was thinking. It's relatively long to put in place, but it's flexible and easy to use after that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide various ResourceBundles for i18N. Then first in your application identify the locale and use that to load the ResourceBundle. Locale specific bundles should have all the translated messages otherwise you can opt to supply the default value too. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/index.html